# I need the product of two functions be understood as a function itself (a Dirac delta example):

Tags: programming, replacement

Define:

In:= Dirac /: Dirac[x_, y_] f_[x_] := f[y]

This works like Dirac's Delta. For example,

In:= h[x] Dirac[x,y]

Out:= h[y]

perfect!  However if I ask:

In:= h[x] k[x] Dirac[x,y]

Out:= h[y] k[x]

It does not change both arguments.
I will apply this with products of functions  f1[x] f2[x] ... fn[x] Dirac[x,y]
and need all arguments to change. How can I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of writing `Dirac[x,y]` after an expression you can write `/. x -> y` after the expression.  Does that do what you want ?

Comment: The product of the distribution DiracDelta and a usual function f[x] is defined under some conditions on f[x] only. See Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function as a first reading.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following definition:

```
Dirac /: Verbatim[Times][a___, Dirac[x_,y_], b___] := Times[a,b] /. x->y
```

Your examples:

```
h[x] Dirac[x,y]
h[x] k[x] Dirac[x, y]
```

> h[y]
>
> h[y] k[y]

Answer (score 1):

The definitions you try to impose on the dirac delta distribution  aren't correct ( theory of distributions )!

```
Integrate[h[x] DiracDelta[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* h[0]  *)    

Integrate[h[x] k[x] DiracDelta[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* h[0] k[0]  *)
```